# RegEx Match is not working

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2012, match

If the result is not a success the Compiler ist just stopping and debug is also just stopping but there is no error, it's just stopping.
If the Result is a success it works but the else part is not working but what can i do if the compiler is just stopping if the Result is a not success?

```
Match Result = Regex.Match(file, pattern);

if(Result.Success)
{
    // This part works
}
else
{
    // this is not working
}
```

There is a try catch arround this, just to mention it.

Comment: show us a test string and your pattern

Comment: "i do if the compiler is just stopping if the Result is a not success": no the execution stops, the compiler does not stop. Compiling is the action of transforming your code into a program executable by the machine. When you are testing that the regexp passes or not, you are in the execution part, not the compiling part.

Answer (score 3):

`else` block is only executed if the `if` block fails. In your case the regex is successfully matching so your `else{ }` isn't executed.

Don't worry if it doesn't match. If regex doesn't match, it will return false and your `else{ }`
will be executed.

Comment: @BlueTrin, you are actually meaning that it is very bad right?

Comment: No, you understood what he meant in his question and addressed the issue, I voted up.

Comment: that's not the Problem. If the Regex is failing the compiler is stopping and debugging is also stopping. It seems like the Match returns nothing or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem lies in the fact that Success is true or false. I tried this code and it works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s1, s2, s0;
            //Regex regex;
            Match match;
            s0 = "l'insostenibile leggerezza dell'essere";
            s1 = "g.+z";
            s2 = "'.*'";
            try
            {
                match = Regex.Match(s0, s1);
                if(match.Success)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
                match = Regex.Match(s0, s2);
                if(match.Success)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
                s1 = "x.+r";
                match = Regex.Match(s0, s1);
                if(match.Success)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Have you checked the clause? Replace your clause in my code and try again.